# Dot keeps appearing in front of numbers, instead of behind in my calculator app

Tags: c#

I am making a calculator app, and everything is done and working except for this weird feature that when I press the "." it first appears in front of the number, but when I keep inputting it moves to the proper position. I have no Idea what may be causing it.

It is also important to note that I made the numbers appear from right to left on the display.

the code for number buttons is basically variations of this:

```
private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = label1.Text + button0.Text;
        }
```

and Dot is :

```
public void buttonDot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                label1.Text = label1.Text + buttonDot.Text;
                buttonDot.Click -= buttonDot_Click;
        }
```

and the other button code is variations of this:

```
public void buttonX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (label1.Text != "")
            {
                Answer.szFvalue = label1.Text;
                label1.Text = "";
            }
            Answer.szOperator = "X";
            if (label1.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                buttonDot.Click -= buttonDot_Click;
            }
            else
            {
                buttonDot.Click += buttonDot_Click;
            }
        }
```

then I have a class to do the calculation:

```
            public string szFvalue;
            public string szOperator;

    public string Answering(string value)
            {
                    if (szOperator == "X")
                    {
                        double Ans = Convert.ToDouble(szFvalue) * Convert.ToDouble(value);
                        return Convert.ToString(Ans);
                    }
                    else if (szOperator == "/")
                    {
                        double Ans = Convert.ToDouble(szFvalue) / Convert.ToDouble(value);
                        return Convert.ToString(Ans);
                    }
                    else if (szOperator == "+")
                    {
                        double Ans = Convert.ToDouble(szFvalue) + Convert.ToDouble(value);
                        return Convert.ToString(Ans);
                    }
                    else if (szOperator == "-")
                    {
                        double Ans = Convert.ToDouble(szFvalue) - Convert.ToDouble(value);
                        return Convert.ToString(Ans);
                    }
                    else if (szOperator == "^")
                    {

                        double Ans = (double)Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(szFvalue), 2);
                        return Convert.ToString(Ans);
                    }
                    else if (szOperator == "Sqrt")
                    {
                        double Ans = Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(szFvalue));
                        return Convert.ToString(Ans);
                    }
                    else if (szOperator == "Log")
                    {
                        double Ans = Math.Log(Convert.ToDouble(szFvalue), 2);
                        return Convert.ToString(Ans);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "error";
                    }
                
            }
```

Comment: why are you unsubscribing to you event handler?
 buttonDot.Click -= buttonDot_Click;
your dots are getting positioned correctly. It is due to RTL setting that you have applied

Comment: When there is a problem i did not see it. Have you tried to debug the problem? Setting breakpoints on the occasions the label content is changed and have a closer look what gets set there and when.

Comment: I am unsubscribing to my event handler buttonDot.Click -= buttonDot_Click; in order to avoid accidentally inputting more than one dot in the number as that breaks the math.

Comment: when taking a look by setting breakpoints it shows the correct placement of the dot in the code, but on the display the dot is still in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround. By putting the text align property to right and then disabling the right to left property, I got the same desired effect but without the drawback of having the dot appear incorrectly.